# AWS Elastic Transcoder Create Job Error

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, boto

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error:

```
    JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
    {u'Message': u'Start of list found where not expected'}
```

It was working fine when I used the output dictionary specified in the api, but when I since I switched to the outputs list of dicts, I've been getting the aforementioned error.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
    transInput = {
    'Key': path,
    'FrameRate': 'auto',
    'Resolution': 'auto',
    'AspectRatio': 'auto',
    'Interlaced': 'auto',
    'Container': 'auto'
}
pprint (transInput)

#Create a job for each desired preset                                       
for pId, descrip in presets.iteritems():
  transOutput = {

        'PresetId': pId,
        'Rotate': 0,
        'ThumbnailPattern': 00001,
        'Key': path +"-" + descrip
        }

    outputs.append(transOutput)



try:
    transcode.create_job(pipelineId, transInput, outputs)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a list of outputs you have to specify that as the `outputs` argument:

```
transcode.create_job(pipelineId, transInput, outputs=output)
```